# How to change bluetooth device type on Mac (e.g. force recognition of bluetooth device as a keyboard)

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

In Bluetooth Preferences on my Mac, my wireless keyboard simply shows up as a bluetooth device and is not recognised as a keyboard.

Is there a way to force the Mac to recognise this device as a keyboard?

The reason I need to do this is so that the keyboard shows up as an option in the "Select Keyboard" drop down in System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier keys.

Please see attached screenshot of device only being recognised as standard bluetooth device.

[image: Bluetooth Devices]

Answer (score 2):

Go into System Preferences > Keyboard and then click on the Set Up Bluetooth keyboard button and see if you are able to properly configure your bluetooth keyboard that way.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark, unfortunately I have just done that and while it does successfully identify my keyboard within that screen, it is still not recognised as a keyboard device in the bluetooth screen (and more importantly is not listed as a keyboard in the Modifier Keys screen).